# Why SelectedStateCallback doesn't work when selecting CheckboxTableCell in javafx 8?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have created demo that shows me problem:

```
package util;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

    public class Demo extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

            ObservableList<Domain> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Domain(true), new Domain(false), new Domain(true));

            TableView<Domain> tableView = new TableView<>(data);

            tableView.setEditable(true);
            tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

            TableColumn column = new TableColumn("Completed");
            column.setEditable(true);
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("completed"));

            column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    CheckBoxTableCell checkBoxTableCell = new CheckBoxTableCell();

                    checkBoxTableCell.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer index) {
                            Domain domain = data.get(index);
                            System.out.println("index=" + index + " " + domain);
                            return domain.getCompleted();
                        }
                    });

                    return checkBoxTableCell;
                }
            });

            tableView.getColumns().add(column);

            Scene scene = new Scene(tableView, 300, 300);
            stage.setTitle("ToDoList");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

        public class Domain {
            private SimpleBooleanProperty completed;

            public Domain(boolean b) {
                super();
                this.completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty(b);
            }

            public SimpleBooleanProperty getCompleted() {
                return completed;
            }

            public void setCompleted(SimpleBooleanProperty completed) {
                this.completed = completed;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Domain [completed=" + completed + "]";
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

So when you run it you can see table with checkboxes. My problem is to get correct `Domain` object when particluar checkbox is clicked.
Table displays state of checkbox depending on `Domain.completed` value.
When checkbox is clicked I want to get corresponding Domain object from `TableView.items`.

I tried to use `checkBoxTableCell.setSelectedStateCallback` but it fires only on startup and not when I click checkbox.

Comment: This looks like it works as expected to me. What are you expecting to happen that is not happening?

Comment: When i click checkbox I need some way to get corresponding Domain object. I used selectedStateCallback for that but it doesn't fire when selecting checkbox. Maybe lambda can help?

Comment: The selected state callback binds the check box state to the returned property. So if you register listeners with the individual properties in the model class, they will see the changes when the check box is selected and unselected.

Comment: Ok, i did that already. And it works. But now when `Domain` object is deleted, how to remove `ChangeListener`. I cannot even get it from `SimpleBooleanProperty`

Comment: If the domain object goes out of scope, then the listener will also be out of scope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selectedStateCallback` provides a `BooleanProperty` to which the selected state of the `CheckBox` is (bidirectionally) bound. Thus in your code, you have ensured the check box always represents the value of the property you define as `completed` in the `Domain` object. Thus, you can just listen for changes to those properties:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    final String item = "Item "+i ;
    Domain d = data.get(i);
    d.getCompleted().addListener((obs, wasCompleted, isNowCompleted) -> {
        System.out.println("Completed state for "+item+" changed from "+wasCompleted+" to "+isNowCompleted);
    });
}
```

Conversely, if you change the properties externally, the check boxes will update:

```
Button selectAll = new Button("Select all");
selectAll.setOnAction(e -> 
    data.forEach(domain -> domain.getCompleted().set(true)));
```

As an aside, your model should follow the [JavaFX Properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). With your current implementation, if you call `setCompleted(...)` on the objects in the list, you will break the check box functionality (as the check box will be bound to the wrong property). You need:

```
public class Domain {
    private final BooleanProperty completed ;

    public Domain(boolean completed) {
        this.completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty(completed);
    }

    public BooleanProperty completedProperty() {
        return completed ;
    }

    public final boolean isCompleted() {
        return completedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
        completedProperty().set(completed);
    }
}
```

with the corresponding change in your `selectedStateCallback`:

```
return domain.completedProperty();
```

Comment: After I changed `TableView.items` collection, `ChangeListener` on `BooleanProperty` stopped working. I solved this issue by adding the listener again!!!

Comment: Well, yes... the listeners are added to the properties of the model, so if you add different items to the table you need to listen to their properties too. You could, depending on your exact needs, perhaps solve this by creating the table's items list using an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-)